# Reference shared maui project from native app

Tags: android, ios, maui

I have a lot of business Logic that I use across cloud, desktops, and now also wanted to use in iOS and Android development.

I can see multiple reference and description of having a .Net Maui app and reference native functionality. But I am looking for the reverse, i.e., being able to have native developers working on their native projects and then reference a .Net Maui/.net 8 shared library is this possible?

What I want to do is what I see [kotlin describe here as Share a piece of logic](https://www.jetbrains.com/kotlin-multiplatform/), can it be done with .Net library?